# Avalanche Node Uptime Decreasing Despite Healthy Node Status

Tags: avalanche

I'm encountering an issue with my Avalanche node's uptime. Although my node's health status is consistently true, I'm experiencing an 86% uptime rate. After closely monitoring the uptime of my peers, I noticed a broad range, with some nodes showing 40-100% uptime and others registering 0-10%. I've attached a screenshot for reference.

**Here are the configuration flags I'm using for my Avalanche node:**

--public-ip --http-port=9650 --http-host=0.0.0.0 --staking-port=9651 --chain-config-dir=/home/ubuntu/configs/chains

My server is running without any significant downtime or issues. I've also checked AvaScan, which reports an uptime of about 99%, but when I query the node info uptime API, it consistently shows 86%. Over time, this figure has been decreasing, and currently, **my uptime stands at 76%.**

**Here are some details about my server configuration:**

- 16 GB RAM
- 8 vCPU
- 2 TB disk
- Ubuntu 20.04

**Additional Information:**

- Node health status is consistently true.
- Peers' uptime ranges from 40-100% to 0-10%.
- The server has no noticeable downtime.
- AvaScan reports 99% uptime.
- Node info uptime API shows 86% and decreasing.

**Screenshots**

[Peers Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vl0K9.png)

[Uptime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZZit.png)

**I'm eager to understand the reasons behind this decreasing uptime and what actions I can take to improve it. Your insights and advice would be greatly appreciated.**